# Internet Explorer 64bit Hyperlink

Tags: internet-explorer

I was wondering if anyone knows how to create a hyperlink shortcut to specifically use 64bit IE. By default my system uses 32bit but there is one particular site that needs to run 64bit IE. Is there anyway to create a shortcut (say on my desktop) to this site and get windows to use 64bit IE instead of 32bit?

Im using 64bit win7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A shortcut to

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" <URL of site>
```

will run the 64-bit IE on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Or just `iexplore <URL>`

Comment: more info here: http://techdows.com/2011/03/install-ie9-32-bit-on-64-bit-windows-7.html

Comment: @RobinJ: `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer` isn't in the default Windows %PATH%.